# No break space is inserted when using multiple line edit in TextMate

Tags: textmate

[image]

I reinstalled the newest TextMate(Version 1.5.10 (1631)) on OS X Lion. It works fine, but when I do multiple line edit and insert space character, I end up having no break space (0xc2 0xa0).

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

As is explained in [this page](http://projects.serenity.de/textmate/tutorials/basics/), non break space is inserted with `alt-space`.

In order to do multiple line selection, one needs to use alt key and mouse drag and drop. What happened was that I didn't release the `alt` key when I clicked the space key.